# How PyCharm decides what library to install

Tags: python, algorithm, pycharm, python-import

If you import a python library and if the library is not installed, PyCharm can automatically install the library for a developer (nice!) (this feature possibly available is other IDEs also). My question is more on how PyCharm determines what library needs to install from the import statement. I could not find a reference or explanation of how it is done. We are doing a study on library dependency management and I am asking the question for that purpose.

For example, consider the following import statement:

```
from wikibot import WikiBot
```

but the library needed for this import is: my-wiki-bot and one need to issue the following command:
`pip install my-wiki-bot` (so, the name does not exactly match). An explanation (i.e., how the decision is made with a link/reference) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm has [python module to pypi package mapping](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/python-psi-impl/resources/tools/packages) inside.

Previously it was built by installing packages from https://pypi.org and inspecting what modules become available after some package installation.

Nowadays this mapping is being updated manually.